# multidimensional array and for loops

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, sfml

I'm using sfml library to make a simple calculator. I have a 2-dimension array that contains the buttons and a 2-dimension array that contains the symbols to put on these buttons.

I created this function:

```
void getButtonClicked()
{
   for (int j=0; j<4;j++)
    {
       for(int k=0;k<4;k++)
         {
           if(sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Left)
             {
                if(buttons[j][k].getGlobalBounds().contains(this->mousePosView)
                 {
                   std::cout << "You have clicked " << symbols[j][k] << std::endl;
                   break; //this is the problem
                 }
             }
         
         }
}
```

After the cout I want to exit the loop so I tried with the break statement but if I start the program and I click a button, the cout is repeated 8 time.

Comment: I don't know SFML, but I'd be surprised if they don't have a button widget you can take advantage of.

Comment: `break` only breaks the inner-most loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
void getButtonClicked()
{
    for (int j=0; j<4;j++) 
    {                       /* After the break, your program goes here,
                               and the outer loop will continue          */
        for(int k=0;k<4;k++)
         {
            if(sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Left)
             {
                 if(buttons[j][k].getGlobalBounds().contains(this->mousePosView)
                 {
                    std::cout << "You have clicked " << symbols[j][k] << std::endl;
                    break; //this is the problem
                 }
             }
         
         }
    }
}
```

Suppose that you can only click 1 button at once, you should use `return` instead

```
void getButtonClicked()
{
    for (int j=0; j<4;j++) 
    {                       
        for(int k=0;k<4;k++)
         {
            if(sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Left)
             {
                 if(buttons[j][k].getGlobalBounds().contains(this->mousePosView)
                 {
                    std::cout << "You have clicked " << symbols[j][k] << std::endl;
                    return;
                 }
             }
         
         }
    }
    /* Using return, your program will exit the function if it found a clicked button */
}
```